# Tag count results page seems inaccurate

Tags: support, tags

If I go to [this example Drupal 8 tagged post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86109/how-to-manage-contrib-modules-composer-dependencies-on-drupal-8), on the right sidebar, it shows `8 x 76` which seems to indicate there are 76 posts tagged with `8`. However, if I then click on the "`8`", I come to page with only 4 posts, "*4 questions tagged*".

But I know there are many more than that and it seems reasonable that 76 is a more accurate number as had showed in the sidebar on the previous single question page. I've noticed this with other tags as well. This behavior seems to have started a few days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the [unanswered](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50) tab.

> [image: screenshot]

If you click on [newest](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8?sort=newest&pageSize=50), you will see the count says 76.

> [image: screenshot]

Keep in mind that the tag tab you visit is remembered for every tag you visit. So, if you visit https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50 and then https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views, you will still see the *unanswered* tab also for [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views).

Comment: ah I see, that was not obvious to me but good to know. Thanks!